# Flutter / When I change the height of the Google Maps, the map area comes out white

Tags: flutter, google-maps, widget, overlay

Why does the map disappear when I change the height?

I need to change the height of the map.

I need to know the center coordinates of the map, so I need to adjust the height.

[image: Google Maps disappearing]

Code:

```dart
class mapTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const mapTest2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<mapTest2> createState() => _mapTest2State();
}

class _mapTest2State extends State<mapTest2> {
  bool isOpen = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(actions: [
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isOpen = !isOpen;
              });

            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.padding))
      ]),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: isOpen ? 300 : 0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey[enter image description here][1],
              child: GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.0, 127.0), zoom: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```